# Dropdown seems not working on version 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've updated my code to twitter bootstrap version 3 and got the https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.0.0/bootstrap-3.0.0-dist.zip.

Still my dropdown menu's won't work. Code:

```
<head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Libre+Baskerville:400,700,400italic|Titillium+Web' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Homestyle.css">    
        <link href="bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

        <title>My Title</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    </head>
<body>
....
....
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Then the actual button dropdowns:

```
<div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delley Hangs</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Mijn profiel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mijn vrienden</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

What's wrong with my code or with the bootstrap? I think it's my fault, but don't know what's wrong!

Edit: Also my `<span class="caret"></span>` are smaller than the actual buttons?

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: No errors, everythings fine over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have your code working in a jsfiddle using Bootstrap 3 CDN and jQuery 1.9.1. Perhaps you should check your jQuery version? I don't actually see jQuery listed in your `<head>` or before `</body>` at all though?

http://jsfiddle.net/remus/VTt7D/

I copied and pasted your code directly, and used this CDN: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: Thanks man, I'm so stupid to forget the jquery. It was implemented in my project before but forgot it to insert it here. Stupid! ;)

Comment: LOL! Hooray! Surprised nothing showed up in the console, but glad it's working for you.